# ScriptAlias having no effect on ability to execute .cgi files

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have enabled alias_module and cgi_module in my apache 2.2 installation. I have added a section:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
   ScriptAlias /digin-cgi/ "/opt/openbdjam/webroot1/push20/digin-cgi/"
</IfModule>
```

my scripts are 'x' executable permissioned and live in the file system directory **/opt/openbdjam/webroot1/push20/digin-cgi**. However, when i go to my webserver (something like the address below) in a browser i just get a 404 not found:

- http://myserver.com/digin-cgi/test.cgi

In case it matters - my server root is set to:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/openbdjam/webroot1"
```

no amount of restarting helps!

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you'll need a directory declaration in there also. Since the cgi-bin is outside your document root, it isn't covered by the 'default'.

```
<Directory "/opt/openbdjam/webroot1/push20/digin-cgi/">
    Options ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Alter your Options and AllowOverride settings as you see fit, but I imagine you'll want ExecCGI as a minimum.

More info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory